# Adding custom rule to jquery validation for checking unique username

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to add a custom rule to check uniqueness of username in my jquery validation function, but it doesn't return any result. When I alert the msg variable it alerts correctly.

Here's my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $("#frmregister").validate({
        rules: {
            "txtName":"required",
            txtuName: {
                required:true,
                usernameCheck:true    // remote check for duplicate username
            },
        },
        messages: {
            txtuName:{
                required:"Please enter User name",
                usernameCheck:"this username is already in use."
            },
        },
        highlight: function( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
            $(element).removeClass(validClass);
        },
        errorElement: 'div'
    });
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod('usernameCheck', function(txtuName) {
    var burl=$("#bseurl").val();

    //alert(burl);
    var postURL = burl+"home/usernamechk";
    //alert(postURL);
    var cnt = $("#frmregister").serialize();

   jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: cnt,
      url: postURL,
      success: function(msg) {
          result = (msg== 2) ? true : false;
      }
      return result;
   });
}, '');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't look like valid Javascript syntax. `return result` is inside an object. But the real problem is that AJAX is asynchronous, so the validator method returns without waiting for results from AJAX.

jquery-validate provides a `remote:` validation method that takes care of waiting for the response. The server just has to return true or false as JSON.